# Mapbox causes crash on notification opening on android - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox

I'm receiving notifications on my application, when I click on it, it opens the application and it works correctly on IOS, it doesn't crash.. But on the Android version, sometimes the application crashes when it's opened by the notification (Especially when the application is running in background).

I checked the Android logs and found out this error :

```
2020-07-15 15:45:11.606 2035-2068/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{f51bf81 u0 com.mapbox.android.telemetry.location.locationupdatespendingintent.action.LOCATION_UPDATED} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@5432fae, started 60002ms ago
2020-07-15 15:45:11.606 2035-2068/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout of BroadcastRecord{f51bf81 u0 com.mapbox.android.telemetry.location.locationupdatespendingintent.action.LOCATION_UPDATED} : BroadcastFilter{f3550dc 10136/u0 ReceiverList{4b6814f 32048 com.pinupapp/10136/u0 remote:5432fae}}
2020-07-15 15:45:11.629 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: dumpStackTraces pids={2408=true, 2456=true, 2594=true, 2777=true, 2811=true, 2843=true, 2913=true, 3175=true, 3818=true, 21771=true, 26312=true, 26389=true, 26449=true, 26493=true, 27694=true, 27865=true, 29505=true, 29786=true, 29853=true, 31048=true, 32135=true, 32233=true} nativepids=[1686, 1808, 1812, 1821, 1822, 1829, 1830, 1831, 1833, 1836, 1853, 1855]
2020-07-15 15:45:11.687 1795-2264/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2020-07-15 15:45:11.687 1795-2264/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2020-07-15 15:45:11.936 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Skipping next CPU consuming process, not a java proc: 2035
2020-07-15 15:45:11.936 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Skipping next CPU consuming process, not a java proc: 1812
2020-07-15 15:45:11.936 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Skipping next CPU consuming process, not a java proc: 2181
2020-07-15 15:45:11.937 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Dumping to /data/anr/anr_2020-07-15-15-45-11-936
2020-07-15 15:45:11.937 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 32048
2020-07-15 15:45:11.937 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 32048
2020-07-15 15:45:11.937 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 32048 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:11.938 32048-32059/com.pinupapp I/com.pinupapp: Thread[7,tid=32059,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8b24bc00,peer=0x9b3026d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.008 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 32048
2020-07-15 15:45:12.008 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 32048 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.008 32048-32059/com.pinupapp I/com.pinupapp: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.013 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 32048
2020-07-15 15:45:12.015 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 2035
2020-07-15 15:45:12.015 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 2035
2020-07-15 15:45:12.015 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 2035 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.015 2035-2047/system_process I/system_server: Thread[7,tid=2047,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8b265400,peer=0x9a7801f0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.160 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2035
2020-07-15 15:45:12.160 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 2035 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.160 2035-2047/system_process I/system_server: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.171 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 2035
2020-07-15 15:45:12.174 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 2513
2020-07-15 15:45:12.174 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 2513
2020-07-15 15:45:12.174 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 2513 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.174 2513-2532/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: Thread[7,tid=2532,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8b24ca00,peer=0x9a980220,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.237 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2513
2020-07-15 15:45:12.237 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 2513 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.237 2513-2532/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.242 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 2513
2020-07-15 15:45:12.244 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 3070
2020-07-15 15:45:12.244 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 3070
2020-07-15 15:45:12.244 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 3070 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.245 3070-3077/com.android.emulator.multidisplay I/or.multidispla: Thread[3,tid=3077,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xe9f34e00,peer=0x9be001a8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.265 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 3070
2020-07-15 15:45:12.265 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 3070 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.266 3070-3077/com.android.emulator.multidisplay I/or.multidispla: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.267 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 3070
2020-07-15 15:45:12.269 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 3015
2020-07-15 15:45:12.269 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 3015
2020-07-15 15:45:12.269 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 3015 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.269 3015-3028/com.android.ims.rcsservice I/.ims.rcsservic: Thread[7,tid=3028,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8b245a00,peer=0x9be40220,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.288 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 3015
2020-07-15 15:45:12.288 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 3015 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.288 3015-3028/com.android.ims.rcsservice I/.ims.rcsservic: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.290 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 3015
2020-07-15 15:45:12.291 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 2976
2020-07-15 15:45:12.291 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 2976
2020-07-15 15:45:12.292 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 2976 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.292 2976-2988/com.android.se I/com.android.se: Thread[6,tid=2988,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8e72d800,peer=0x9bc40220,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.311 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2976
2020-07-15 15:45:12.311 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 2976 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.311 2976-2988/com.android.se I/com.android.se: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.312 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 2976
2020-07-15 15:45:12.314 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 2279
2020-07-15 15:45:12.314 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 2279
2020-07-15 15:45:12.314 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 2279 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.315 2279-2295/com.google.android.networkstack I/id.networkstac: Thread[5,tid=2295,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8b243e00,peer=0x9a880220,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.340 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2279
2020-07-15 15:45:12.340 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 2279 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.340 2279-2295/com.google.android.networkstack I/id.networkstac: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.342 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 2279
2020-07-15 15:45:12.344 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 2353
2020-07-15 15:45:12.344 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 2353
2020-07-15 15:45:12.344 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 2353 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.344 2353-2360/com.android.phone I/m.android.phon: Thread[3,tid=2360,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xe9f34e00,peer=0x9a8401a8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.388 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2353
2020-07-15 15:45:12.388 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 2353 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.388 2353-2360/com.android.phone I/m.android.phon: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.393 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 2353
2020-07-15 15:45:12.395 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for pid 2181
2020-07-15 15:45:12.395 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 2181
2020-07-15 15:45:12.395 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 2181 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.396 2181-2191/com.android.systemui I/ndroid.systemu: Thread[5,tid=2191,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x8b243e00,peer=0x9b405ca8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2020-07-15 15:45:12.476 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2181
2020-07-15 15:45:12.476 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 2181 and type kDebuggerdJavaBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.477 2181-2191/com.android.systemui I/ndroid.systemu: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2020-07-15 15:45:12.480 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 2181
2020-07-15 15:45:12.482 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1686
2020-07-15 15:45:12.482 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1686
2020-07-15 15:45:12.482 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1686 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.482 1686-1686/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1686 (Binder:1686_2)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.489 32366-32366/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.489 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1686
2020-07-15 15:45:12.490 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1686 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.490 32366-32366/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1686 (target tid = 1686)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.496 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1686
2020-07-15 15:45:12.498 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1808
2020-07-15 15:45:12.498 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1808
2020-07-15 15:45:12.499 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1808 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.499 1808-1808/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1808 (audioserver)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.507 32371-32371/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.508 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1808
2020-07-15 15:45:12.508 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1808 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.508 32371-32371/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1808 (target tid = 1808)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.516 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1808
2020-07-15 15:45:12.518 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1812
2020-07-15 15:45:12.519 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1812
2020-07-15 15:45:12.519 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1812 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.519 1812-1812/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1812 (surfaceflinger)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.528 32376-32376/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.529 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1812
2020-07-15 15:45:12.530 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1812 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.530 32376-32376/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1812 (target tid = 1812)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.541 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1812
2020-07-15 15:45:12.543 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1821
2020-07-15 15:45:12.543 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1821
2020-07-15 15:45:12.544 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1821 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.544 1821-1821/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1821 (cameraserver)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.551 32381-32381/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.551 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1821
2020-07-15 15:45:12.551 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1821 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.552 32381-32381/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1821 (target tid = 1821)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.557 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1821
2020-07-15 15:45:12.560 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1822
2020-07-15 15:45:12.560 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1822
2020-07-15 15:45:12.560 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1822 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.560 1822-1822/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1822 (drmserver)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.567 32386-32386/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.567 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1822
2020-07-15 15:45:12.567 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1822 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.567 32386-32386/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1822 (target tid = 1822)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.570 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1822
2020-07-15 15:45:12.572 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1829
2020-07-15 15:45:12.572 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1829
2020-07-15 15:45:12.573 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1829 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.573 1829-1829/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1829 (mediadrmserver)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.579 32391-32391/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.579 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1829
2020-07-15 15:45:12.579 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1829 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.579 32391-32391/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1829 (target tid = 1829)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.582 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1829
2020-07-15 15:45:12.584 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1830
2020-07-15 15:45:12.584 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1830
2020-07-15 15:45:12.584 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1830 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.585 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1830
2020-07-15 15:45:12.585 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1830 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.608 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1830
2020-07-15 15:45:12.609 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1831
2020-07-15 15:45:12.609 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1831
2020-07-15 15:45:12.610 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1831 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.610 1831-1831/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1831 (mediametrics)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.617 32396-32396/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.617 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1831
2020-07-15 15:45:12.617 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1831 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.617 32396-32396/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1831 (target tid = 1831)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.620 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1831
2020-07-15 15:45:12.622 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1833
2020-07-15 15:45:12.622 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1833
2020-07-15 15:45:12.622 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1833 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.622 1833-1833/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1833 (mediaserver)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.631 32401-32401/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.631 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1833
2020-07-15 15:45:12.631 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1833 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.631 32401-32401/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1833 (target tid = 1833)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.639 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1833
2020-07-15 15:45:12.641 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1836
2020-07-15 15:45:12.641 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1836
2020-07-15 15:45:12.641 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1836 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.641 1836-1836/? I/libc: Requested dump for tid 1836 (Binder:1836_2)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.648 32406-32406/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.648 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1836
2020-07-15 15:45:12.649 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1836 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.649 32406-32406/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 1836 (target tid = 1836)
2020-07-15 15:45:12.669 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1836
2020-07-15 15:45:12.671 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1853
2020-07-15 15:45:12.671 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1853
2020-07-15 15:45:12.671 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1853 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.672 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1853
2020-07-15 15:45:12.672 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1853 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.687 1795-2264/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2020-07-15 15:45:12.687 1795-2264/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2020-07-15 15:45:12.709 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1853
2020-07-15 15:45:12.710 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Collecting stacks for native pid 1855
2020-07-15 15:45:12.711 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: started dumping process 1855
2020-07-15 15:45:12.711 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: registered intercept for pid 1855 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.711 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1855
2020-07-15 15:45:12.711 1857-1857/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: found intercept fd 512 for pid 1855 and type kDebuggerdNativeBacktrace
2020-07-15 15:45:12.730 2035-2068/system_process I/system_server: libdebuggerd_client: done dumping process 1855
2020-07-15 15:45:12.732 2035-2068/system_process I/ActivityManager: Done dumping
2020-07-15 15:45:12.732 2035-2068/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.pinupapp
    PID: 32048
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.mapbox.android.telemetry.location.locationupdatespendingintent.action.LOCATION_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
    Load: 0.2 / 0.09 / 0.1
    CPU usage from 215127ms to 0ms ago (2020-07-15 15:41:36.483 to 2020-07-15 15:45:11.610):
      11% 1812/surfaceflinger: 0.5% user + 10% kernel / faults: 150 minor
      5.6% 2181/com.android.systemui: 1.1% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 6063 minor
      4.4% 2035/system_server: 0.8% user + 3.5% kernel / faults: 22738 minor 1 major
      1.4% 2594/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.4% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 11065 minor
      1.2% 1798/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 0% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 22 minor
      1.2% 1802/android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
      0.9% 1784/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
      0.4% 1817/adbd: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 299 minor
      0.3% 2843/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 8557 minor 4 major
      0% 1808/audioserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor
      0% 1786/android.hardware.audio@2.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.2% 1814/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 5 minor
      0.2% 1681/logd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 4 minor
      0% 1797/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 31 minor
      0% 2456/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 977 minor
      0.1% 1836/statsd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 27 minor
      0.1% 2777/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 684 minor 2 major
      0% 2353/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 138 minor
      0% 1795/android.hardware.gnss@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 29052/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
      0% 1860/llkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 31992/kworker/u8:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1682/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1807/ashmemd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1833/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 450 minor
      0% 1804/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 26389/com.android.chrome: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 21 minor
      0% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1701/jbd2/vdc-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 29769/kworker/0:4: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1810/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 31861/kworker/u8:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 7/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 867/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1779/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 125 minor
      0% 1780/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 490 minor
      0% 1853/media.codec: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 68 minor
      0% 26312/com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.Sand: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 667 minor
      0% 17/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1785/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1851/wificond: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
      0% 2408/com.google.android.ext.services: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 192 minor
      0% 30108/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 9/rcu_sched: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 12/watchdog/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 29/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 356/khugepaged: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1688/kworker/1:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1790/android.hardware.configstore@1.1-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor 50 major
      0% 1830/media.extractor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
      0% 1854/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1855/media.swcodec: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1859/android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 2279/com.google.android.networkstack: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 39 minor
      0% 2371/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 2513/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
      0% 2811/com.google.process.gservices: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 29 minor
      0% 26449/com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedPro: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 26493/com.android.chrome:privileged_process0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 31962/kworker/3:
```

Based on this error, I guess it comes from Mapbox but I don't really know how to fix it? Did someone already had this problem and fixed it?

Comment: There is no enough log to check it, please list the stack about current process. But the anr with Broadcast maybe caused by lots of operations that cost time in Receiver.

Comment: I added the logs that appeared before the errors, idk if it gives you more information, I'm kinda lost in those logs

Comment: "Receiver during timeout of BroadcastRecord    Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord" ,  these logs indicate that the receiver in "com.pinupapp/10136/u0" timeout.  Please check where the receiver do time consuming operations.   If not found, you could look up from "/data/anr/anr_2020-07-15-15-45-11-936 "at same time.